# XsltListViewWebPart onet problem in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, xslt-list-view-web-part

I´m migrating a site from SP 2010 to SP 2013. I have a XsltListViewWebPart included in the onet of a page.
In SP 2010 it works properly, all the categories appears and when I click on it, it expands and show all the documents.
In SP 2013 it works in the same way but I have to click twice in the category in order to expand the documents.
I tryed two ways to include the webpart in the onet but none works.

```
<View List="Lists/PublicDocuments" BaseViewID="1" WebPartZoneID="ContentWebPart75HightTop2" WebPartOrder="1" Type="HTML">
<![CDATA[
      <WebPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2" >
      <Title>Public Documents</Title>
      <FrameType>None</FrameType>
      <Assembly>Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c</Assembly>
      <TypeName>Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.XsltListViewWebPart</TypeName>
      </WebPart>

    ]]>
</View>
```

-

```
<View List="Lists/PublicDocuments" BaseViewID="1" WebPartZoneID="ContentWebPart75HightTop2" WebPartOrder="2" Type="HTML">
      <![CDATA[
      <webParts>
          <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
              <metaData>
                  <type name="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.XsltListViewWebPart,Microsoft.SharePoint,Version=15.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
                  <importErrorMessage>Cannot import this Web Part.</importErrorMessage>
              </metaData>
              <data>
                  <properties>
                      <property name="Title" type="string">Public Documents</property>
                      <property name="DisableViewSelectorMenu" type="bool">True</property>
                      <property name="InplaceSearchEnabled" type="bool">False</property>
                      <property name="ShowToolbarWithRibbon" type="bool">False</property>
                      <property name="ExportMode" type="exportmode">All</property>
                      <property name="ChromeType" type="chrometype">None</property>
                      <property name="NoDefaultStyle" type="string" null="true" />
                  </properties>
              </data>
          </webPart>
      </webParts>
  ]]>
    </View>
```

If I include the XsltListViewWebPart directly in the layout, it works fine.

```
<WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart ID="XsltListViewWebPart2" 
                        runat="server" ListUrl="Lists/PublicDocuments" IsIncluded="True" NoDefaultStyle="TRUE" Title="Public Documents" PageType="PAGE_NORMALVIEW" FrameType="None" Default="False" ViewContentTypeId="0x" ExportMode="All" ExportControlledProperties="true">
</WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart>
```